# Convert csv to xlsx using cmd

Tags: excel, csv, cmd

I'm working in a solution that creates a .csv file in a server and download it to the user machine.

I would like to download it as a .xlsx file.

I have access to the server using SQLPlus (where I can use command lines if necessary) and I know the server does not have Excel installed.

Is that a way to convert the .csv file?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to open/use the .csv in Excel? Why not just open the .csv directly?  Why require a conversion?  What have you tried? Does [this page](http://access-excel.tips/vba-convert-csv-to-excel/) help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the .csv to be an .xlsx, then open blank Excel document.

*Note: I am using Excel 2013.*

1. Make sure you have clicked in top left cell, A1, and that it is
   blank.
2. Click "DATA" tab at the top.
3. Click "From Text" option.
4. It will open up browsing option.
5. Find the .csv file you want to open/"convert".
6. Click import.
7. Once it is open, you can pick to have it Delimited by tabs, spaces, or commas.
8. Click next.
9. Pick the delimiters you need it separated by, so that it will fill out the columns.
10. Click finish.
11. It will ask where to put, and it you selected A1 in the steps above it will default there and just click okay.
12. Now save the file as an .xlsx file and you are done.